# How to get unused variable warning from the header file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm working in the process of removing bunch of C code that used variables that were declared in a header file. My compiler doesn't warn of unused variable from the header file for whatever reason. What's option to invoke unused variable from a header file. It does it from the C file though.

Comment: You don't get those because other C files might include the header and use the variables. If you wanted to get those you'd have to temporarily move them into a C file.

Comment: Defining a variable in a header file is generally considered bad practice - You can *declare* it, but should not *define* it. And if it is only *declared* there and unused, there is normally no warning from the compiler (it just doesn't do anything, but at no cost). Are you sure you are really *defining* variables there? Can you give some examples?

Comment: Unless a compiler can see _all_ the source files that included `foo.h`, it cannot know if a `foo.h` declared object is not used.  Sounds like a job for the linker.

Comment: @chux The compiler is not even aware that it is processing a *header* - After the preprocessing stage, the compiler cannot even distinguish variables from a header from those from a .c file. Something is wrong with this question.

Comment: @tofro: My bad. It was declared not defined. I changed my OP to reflect that.

Comment: @Kitcha Then there is no difference on whether a variable is declared in a header or in the main .c file - Compilers do not warn when a variable is *declared and unused* - as opposed to *defined and unused*

Answer (score 2):

First, the *compiler* as such is not even aware on whether a variable is declared in a header file or in the .c file - After the preprocessor has run, this is indistinguishable.

What you normally declare in a header file is **external references**, i.e. variables of storage class `external`. No compiler I know warns if such a variable is unused - A lot of system header files declare such variables, and you'd be flooded with warnings if it did (`errno` or `stderr` are notable examples - You don't want to be warned for any source file that doesn't use `errno` or `stderr`)

Compilers can issue warnings for unused `static` variables, and unused function parameters. The usage and scope of such variables is limited to the current compilation unit or function and "noone else could possibly use them", so it makes sense to warn. `extern` variables can very well be used by other object files, for those the compiler would not be able to issue a warning - A proper linker, however would realize that an external symbol is not used by any object file and silently remove that variable from the final executable - No warning needed, as it can be fixed by the compilation system.

Answer (score 0):

For C-compiler there is no difference between header (included) and any other C-source file.

Compiler doesn't have to emit warning message about unused global data, since this data may be used by another software.

If you have a concern that a piece of data is used only in scope of single object file, try to prepend this data definition with `static` keyword, rebuild and run you software. If after some time everything still works fine and you know for sure any possible (lazy) dynamic linking will still be happy to loose piece of global data you just removed - it is really 100% safe to remove it.

Comment: Your  last proposal is probably not a good idea: If the same header with the same `static` definition (`static`is *always* a definition) is included in 15 source files, you'll have 15 instances of that same variable spread across your code - Whereas if you left it as it is was (no `static`) the linker would have complained about multiple definitions. Your proposal only makes sense in a .c file.

Comment: On second thought, you get a warning for non-used `static`s - So it might really help detecting places that don't use that variable.

Comment: As soon as your answer says that ;) At the moment, it doesn't

Comment: On third thought, I cannot give you +1, because you recommend a declaration in the header - I disagree with that.

Comment: @tofro Declaration in header file? Show me a programmer who says it is right and we will blame him together :D